# How to concatenate a bit to the end of a bit string?

Tags: elixir

I'm looking to construct a bit string bit by bit, and am wondering how to do so.

I was expecting the syntax to be similar to concatenating two bytes like so:

```
iex(1)> <<1>> <> <<1>>
<<1, 1>>
```

So I tried:

```
iex(2) <<1::1>> <> <<1::1>>
** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if it's a bug or not, but let's explore what's going on and worry about that later.

What is `<>`? It turns out it's just a macro defined in [`Kernel.<>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%3C%3E/2). What can we do with macros to understand them better? Expand them!

```
quote(do: <<1::1>> <> <<1::1>>) 
|> Macro.expand(__ENV__) 
|> Macro.to_string
#=> "<<(<<1::1>>::binary), (<<1::1>>::binary)>>"
```

We can see that `<>` desugars to the normal binary syntax. Unfortunately for us it assumes it's arguments are binaries! We have bitstrings - hence the error. How to fix it? We can use the regular binary/bitstring syntax directly:

```
<< <<1::1>>::bitstring, <<1::1>>::bitstring >>
#=> <<3::size(2)>>
```

Which works as expected.

EDIT: I followed up on this. This behaviour is expected. `<>` operator is designed to work on binaries and not bitstrings. The error is rather unpleasant, but it's coming deep from within Erlang.

Comment: That's awesome thank you! I started going down that path but didn't quite have the skills to get where you got me. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure if the syntax has changed or whether you were using `::bitstring` for explanatory purposes, but it can also be written simply `<<1::1, 1::1>>` unless you are using variables, then it needs to be added: `<<existing::bitstring, append::bitstring>>`.